# My laptop AC adapter is not found when plugged in

Tags: power-management, laptop, acpi

Three different Linux OS installed on my [Acer Predator Helios 500 PH517-61-R0GX](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/7737?b=1) say the AC adapter is "off-line". Unplugging and re-plugging does not change the status. My laptop thinks it is on battery constantly and shows as "discharging", but the discharge rate is always at 0. Therefore my laptop runs in a power-save mode, and the resulting sluggish performance prevents game play or anything demanding.

Is there a way to force the AC adapter device to report as "on-line"?
Is there a way to generate a fake AC adapter device that will read as "on-line"?
Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Edit: OS is Artix Linux, kernel 5.0.4 but I have also tested Manjaro and Ubuntu with the same results.

dmesg shows:
`[    9.514590] ACPI: AC Adapter [ACAD] (on-line)`

But once you login XFCE shows the AC adapter as off-line.

acpi -V:
`Adapter 0: off-line`

From reading online I am not the only one who is experiencing this, but everyone who has installed Linux on this laptop model.

Comment: Welcome to UNIX&Linux Stack Exchange. @K7AAY has already provided some guidance on how to dig further into the issue in their comment. I would like to suggest you edit your question and provide more detail that may help others who have a similar problem or have solved a similar problem. You post has absolutely zero technical details. Operating System? Make, model, part no. of laptop? Does this problem occur in all operating systems, or just the flavor of *NIX you are trying? https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for the updates, _quad cricket_. I suggest obtaining an inexpensive voltmeter to confirm the power adapter output voltage matches the voltage specified on the serial number plate of the laptop, to rule out a low voltage issue with the power supply (which has been seen en masse before with other makes).

Comment: The power adapter voltage read at a nice 19.7v until I shorted it and now it reads 0v. Apparently the hot pin shorted to a ground sleeve inside the port and there is no fuse that I can see. The wires at the base of the adapter still read fine so the brick itself seems okay but I have no idea where to order just the barrel from. Anyone know where to get a different, but compatible, power adapter? 19.5v 16.9A compatible with model: ADP-330AB D